ERR_HTTP2_COMPRESSION_ERROR while downloading a file
I am using libwebsockets C++ library for my http server. 
I can download a file using API with postman

Response Headers content-type: application/zip content-length: 107627
cache-control: no-store Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename=logs.zip

I tried with cURL, which is successful:
curl --http1.1 -k -OJ https://x.x.x.x/api/files/download-logfile  

But when I use Chrome browser I see error:

The webpage at https://x.x.x.x/api/files/download-logfile might be
temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web
address. ERR_HTTP2_COMPRESSION_ERROR

I tried to enable in library; still same problem
-DLWS_WITH_HTTP2=ON
-DLWS_WITH_HTTP_STREAM_COMPRESSION=1

What could be the problem here? Am I missing anything here?

Chrome is probably sending an 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br', I'm curious if the curl call fails with a similar error if you send the same header.

@James: Next time, please fix all the problems, but don’t fix problems that don’t exist.  And enter a meaningful edit summary.
